# Redux axios cancellation config issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I create middleware layer for all request in my app and use [axios doc](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation) 
for cancellation multiple requests, but I can't understand why axios throw a cancel error for all my request now:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

export default (method, url, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const fullUrl = resolveUrl(url);

        let config = {
            cancelToken:  source.token,
            method: method || 'POST',
            url: fullUrl
        };

        isObject(params) && (method === 'GET' ? config.params = params : config.data = params);

        return axios(config).then(response => {
            resolve(response);
        }).catch(err => {
            if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
                log.error(` Error ${err.message}`);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
};

source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');
```

Comment: what is the error shown?

Comment: @nivas `Error Operation canceled by the user.`

Comment: Why have you added `source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');` at the end of the file? The doc just says, you can use the cancellation when you require, not always to cancel it

Comment: need to check if(prevParams === params) and then use source.cancel();

Comment: Yes, and hence cancelling upfront wont provide any help.